# Mysql: How to prevent users from having read only access to all databases' tables?

Tags: mysql

I have mysql 5.0.82sp1 running and i've noticed that all users can invoke select command on all databases' tables. They don't have privileges to do so, so there's nothing i can revoke. Is there some mysql setting granting this read-only access by default?

this seems to always give result

`select * from some_database_name.some_table_name`

and it shows whatever is in it.

it works even if i revoke all privileges by issuing command

`revoke all privileges, grant option  from 'username'@'localhost';`

and i check it by issuing command

`show grants;`

it shows

`GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...'`

which means it doesn't have privileges to select

Comment: Are you using a test database ???

Comment: as i'm writting user can read from ALL databases

Answer (score 3):

Because you change **global** privileges, so you need to do the following to make it take effects:

1. issue a `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` statement to reload the grant tables
2. disconnect the current client and reconnect

[Read more...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privilege-changes.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is something disturbing about this behavior.

I can only think of two circumstances when SELECTs can run unrestained like this:

**SITUATION #1: skip-grant-tables in /etc/my.cnf**

Please check that /etc/my.cnf does not have this:

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

If it does, remove the `skip-grant-tables` line and restart mysql right away.

**SITUATION #2: skip-grant-tables from command line**

It is possible to start mysql with the `skip-grant-tables` option without touching my.cnf. In Linux OS, please run this:

```
$ service mysql start --skip-grant-tables
```

From the Linux command line, to find out if `skip-grant-tables` is activated, pleasd run this:

```
$  mysqld --help --verbose | grep -C 3 "skip-grants"
```

You will see lines that look something like this:

```
secure-file-priv                                  (No default value)
server-id                                         106451130
show-slave-auth-info                              FALSE
skip-grant-tables                                 FALSE
skip-name-resolve                                 TRUE
skip-networking                                   FALSE
skip-show-database                                FALSE
```

If `skip-grant-tables` is TRUE, just restart mysql as normal. It should then disappear.

Give it a Try !!!

CAVEAT : If this is a MySQL/Windows issue, please inspect my.ini

Also, there is no global variable to change this feature. This option applies to the startup of mysql only.

**UPDATE 2011-09-09 12:56 EDT**

Try using this SQL Command once you login:

```
SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
```

These functions report the way you authenticate

[USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_user) reports how you attempted to authenticate in MySQL

[CURRENT_USER()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_current-user) reports how you were allowed to authenticate in MySQL

Please update your question with these findings !!!

Comment: unfortunately skip-grant-tables says false. And as i checked on other server, i found same issue. So i was wondering if you could do me a favour, and loggin to any mysql server you have access to and log in as user and try to issue those commands with databasename user doesn't have privileges to use and tell me if this work 'use somedatabasename; show tables;'

Answer (score 0):

As from your grant command (**USAGE ON *.***) it seems like you have granted access to all the databases. Update the privilege by restricting access only to the particular database for the corresponding user. ie, USAGE ON **databasename.*** instead of ***.***